# How to calculate milliseconds since beginning of the day?

Tags: javascript, date, time

I've specified a specific time on a certain day. Now I wish to calculate the milliseconds from the beginning of that specific day to the set time of that day? I was hoping to do that with below code, but instead it shows nothing? What am I doing wrong?

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
var oneday = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var countDownDate = new Date("January 10, 2018 00:01").getTime();
var countDownStart = new Date(countDownDate.getFullYear(), countDownDate.getMonth(), countDownDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0); 
var countDownTime = countDownDate.getTime() - countDownStart.getTime();

var div = document.getElementById('result'); 
div.innerText = countDownTime;
```

I specify the countDownDate. Then I mark the beginning of that countDownDate into the variable countDownStart. Next I calculate the time passed since 00:00 of January 10 to 00:01 of January 10 by subtracting countDownStart from countDownDate. But no result is shown...

Comment: You can use moment library.it will be usefull

Comment: @31piy sometimes its easy to understand moment.doing these much of stuff.

Comment: @31piy nowadays there are lots of bundlers and methods to reduce the bundle size if he needs to load the library he lazyload also.so that's depends

Comment: @31piy ohk..but also there is lots of methods to tackle that.eg.zip.lazy loading etc.. So readability is to be taken care.

Comment: Please don't use the built-in parser,  see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results). Instead of `new Date("January 10, 2018 00:01")` use `new Date(2018, 0, 10, 0, 1)` which is not only more robust but also less to type. ;-) Also, not all days are 24 hrs long where daylight saving is observed (some are longer, some shorter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is fine here. The only issue is this line here:

```
var countDownDate = new Date("January 10, 2018 00:01").getTime();
```

Since you used `.getTime()` the variable `countDownDate` is no longer a date. As such in the following statement`countDownDate.getFullYear()` and forward isn't going to work. Simply remove `.getTime()` and it will work as expected:

```js
var now = new Date().getTime();
var oneday = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var countDownDate = new Date("January 10, 2018 00:01");
var countDownStart = new Date(countDownDate.getFullYear(), countDownDate.getMonth(), countDownDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0); 
var countDownTime = countDownDate.getTime() - countDownStart.getTime();

console.log(countDownTime)
```

Comment: There's no need for *getTime* at all, the difference can be just `countDownDate - countDownStart`. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Your code has only one issue, and that is that you've assigned the result of `.getTime()` to `countDownDate`, which will be a number.

That's why JavaScript cannot call `getFullYear`, or any other function on that number, because those will be invalid calls.

To correct that, just remove the `.getTime()`, and it will work fine.

```js
var now = new Date().getTime();
var oneday = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var countDownDate = new Date("January 10, 2018 00:01");
var countDownStart = new Date(countDownDate.getFullYear(), countDownDate.getMonth(), countDownDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
var countDownTime = countDownDate.getTime() - countDownStart.getTime();

var div = document.getElementById('result');
div.innerText = countDownTime;
```

```html
<div id="result">
  <div>
```

Comment: Looks like you beat me by a few seconds :)